# Combobox plus String name

Tags: vb.net

Hello i have  comboboxes with the name ("Combobox1", "Combobox1a", "Combobox2", "Combobox2a", "combobox3" "Combobox3a"). When the selectedindex in combobox1 changed, combobox1a will add 4 items. The same with combobox2 and 2a, combobox3 and 3a. When i do this i have to code it in combobox1, combobox2 and combobox3. So ill try to make a method so that when the selectedindexchange in combobox it will call this method.

heres my code.

```
     Dim cmbName as String = ""

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
     cmbName = "1"
     cmbSelectedIndexChanged()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
         cmbName = "2"
     cmbSelectedIndexChanged()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged
       cmbName = "3"
     cmbSelectedIndexChanged()

    End Sub



    Private Sub cmbSelectedIndexChanged()
    "combobox" & cmbName.Items.add("data1")
"combobox" & cmbName.Items.add("data2")
"combobox" & cmbName.Items.add("data3")
"combobox" & cmbName.Items.add("data4")
     End Sub
```

I just want to make my code smaller so that everytime my combobox index change it will only call the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the other combo in your controls collection like this

`combo = CType(Me.Controls.Find("combobox1", True)(0), ComboBox)`

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
     cmbSelectedIndexChanged("1")
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
     cmbSelectedIndexChanged("2")
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged
     cmbSelectedIndexChanged("3")
End Sub

Private Sub cmbSelectedIndexChanged(cmbName as string)
    Dim Combo as ComboBox = CType(Me.Controls.Find("combobox" & cmbName), ComboBox)
    Combo.Items.add("data1")
    Combo.Items.add("data2")
    Combo.Items.add("data3")
    Combo.Items.add("data4")
 End Sub
```

Comment: I got this error. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: So i try to put new "  Dim ComboName As new ComboBox = CType(Me.Controls("cmb" & cmbName & "Unit"), ComboBox)" but its the same

Comment: oops, try `Me.Controls.Find` instead.